# SQL count (*) function query for a baseball data table explanation

Tags: sql, function, count

This line of code is simple and I understand what the query will return. I am trying to understand the third line of this code.

```
   select First 
, sum(rbi) as 'rbis' 
**, count(*) as 'num_players'** 
from #batter_stats 
group by First 
having count(*) >= 5 
order by [rbis] desc
```

The `count(*) as 'num_players'` is confusing me as to what this does in this query.
[image: Data query]

[image: The data table]

Thanks you. I provided both the line of code and the data table.

Comment: `count(*)` here simply means the row count, `having count(*) > = 5` means that there must be at least 5 rows.

Comment: On a side note: The query is invalid. The SQL delimiter for names is the the double quote `"`. Some DBMS want brackets instead. You are using them here: `order by [rbis] desc`. But single quotes are for string literals. So `as 'rbis'` is incorrect and should be `as "rbis"` or `as '[rbis]` or just `as rbis` instead. As all your names are valid names in SQL, I suggest you remove the quotes and brackets completely. They are not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code the aggregation functions

```
  , sum(rbi) as rbis
  ,  count(*) as num_players
```

agregated  by  column `First`

`count(*)`  retunr the number of  rows  for the corresponding groped  value

so in your case retunr the number of rows in your table for the corresponding value of olumn `First`

Comment: There is no such thing as a `NULL` row.  `COUNT(*)` returns the number of rows.